# Aws lamda moving all xmls from on bucket to another bucket - Python

Tags: boto3

I have a requirement where I have two buckets example Bucket1 and bucket2. 
Bucket1 contains all XML  files. I want to move all xmls files form bucketA to BucketB (all files).
and then Delete All files form BucketA.

I am using Boto3 with Python lambda function - This will trigger event-based once any file updated in BucketA

Comment: What have you tried so far? Kindly post your code, Please do refer the community guidelines, This platform is not a solution provider for your usecases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below:

```
import boto

c = boto.connect_s3()
src = c.get_bucket('source_bucket')
dst = c.get_bucket('destination_bucket')

for k in src.list():
    # copy files to your destination bucket
    dst.copy_key(k.key.name, src.name, k.key.name)
    # then delete the source key
    k.delete()
```

**Another method i have done as below:**

```
def get_object(s3, bucketName, file):

    try:
        s3_file = s3.get_object(
        Bucket = bucketName,
        Key = file
        )


        return s3_file

    except Exception as e:

        logger.info('file not found')



#Decription: This method enables to put file long with its conetent from one location to another
def move_objects(s3, bucketName, file, newFolder):

    #s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketName, Key=file)

    #serializedObject = file['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

    response = s3.put_object(
        Bucket = bucketName,
        Key = newFolder,
        Body = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        )


#Decription: This method enables to delete file from its original location
def delete_objects(s3, bucketName, file):

    response = s3.delete_object(
        Bucket = bucketName,
        Key = file

        )
```

Also, Refer this video:
https://youtu.be/7gqvV4tUxmY